Can't remove back button title, nor change tint color when pushing UIViewController from SwiftUI view via UIViewControllerRepresentable
I have a SwiftUI NavigationView and a SwiftUI view displayed in SwiftUI. The navigation link refers to a UIViewControllerRepresentable wrapping a UIViewController. I have been unable to remove the back button title, nor have I been able to set the tint of the back button when navigating to this UIKit view controller. This is targeting iOS 15.
Here's a minimal application that attempts it. I had similar issue just setting the Title for the UIKit view controller, but found reference to the SwiftUI modifier on the NavigationLink. I haven't found other modifiers for tint nor removing back button title.
I've also seen references that this needs to be done after the view controller moves to a wrapper parent controller that SwiftUI creates during this process. I've tried putting it in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, init(), didMove(toParent:, willMove(toParent. These work for setting the title but not for setting the tint nor removing back button text.
I've tried setting backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal in a bunch of places with confusing results.
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .systemPink
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MyViewControllerRepresentable()
                    .navigationTitle("TitleFromSwiftUI")) {
                    Text("MyVC")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Top")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct MyViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyViewController {
        return MyViewController()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: Context) {}
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Nested view" // Doesn't work when pushed from SwiftUI view
        navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal // Only works for nested views
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .systemPink // Never works
        let button = UIButton(primaryAction: UIAction { _ in
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MyViewController(), animated: true)
        })
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 150, width: 200, height: 20)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


What iOS version are you targeting? Can you use NavigationStack instead?

iOS 15... which doesn't have NavigationStack.
